# Is there a way to determine the type of a Pointer?

Tags: delphi

Let's say I have these types and variables:

```
type

TMyStruct1 = record
  Int1        : Integer;
  Int2        : Integer;
  Str1        : String;
  Str2        : String;
end;
PMyStruct1 = ^TMyStruct1;

TMyStruct2 = record
  Int1        : Integer;
  Int2        : Integer;
  Str1        : String;
  Str2        : String;
end;
PMyStruct2 = ^TMyStruct2;

var

P1: PMyStruct1;
P2: PMyStruct2;
```

I have a function that acepts Pointer as an argument. Is there a way to determine if the function is called with P1 or P2 variable?

Something like:

```
function DoSomething(P: Pointer);
begin
 //if  ??? Type(P) = PMyStruct1 ??? then ....
```

Comment: Introspection is typically a feature of interpreted languages (Java, C#, Python). Compiled languages (C++, Delphi) usually do not implement this natively.

Comment: No, you can not determine if the function was called with P1 or P2.

Comment: You cannot even determine if you've got a *valid* pointer or not.

Comment: FWIW, instead of records, think of using simple classes. You can check the type of a class instance.

Comment: If you need only the type of a variable, then with certain reservations, this can be achieved using generics.

Comment: @Vasek No, that's not the case. There is no solution to this question that is based on generics.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve that by adding a "standard header" to your structure. In your case, a simple field indicating the type of your structure would be sufficient.

```
const 
  STRUCT_1 = 1;
  STRUCT_2 = 2;
type

TMyStruct1 = record
  StructType  : Integer
  Int1        : Integer;
  Int2        : Integer;
  Str1        : String;
  Str2        : String;
end;
PMyStruct1 = ^TMyStruct1;

TMyStruct2 = record
  StructType  : Integer
  Int1        : Integer;
  Int2        : Integer;
  Str1        : String;
  Str2        : String;
end;
PMyStruct2 = ^TMyStruct2;

var

P1: PMyStruct1;
P2: PMyStruct2;

function DoSomething(P: Pointer);
begin
  case PInteger(P)^ of //points to StructType
    STRUCT_1 : ;
    STRUCT_2 : ;
  end;
end;
```

Whoever is calling your function would be responsible to properly feed the `StructType` field.

As a forward compatibility measure, you could also add a "StructSize" field in case you end up needing multiple version of each structure.

This kind of type checking is "weak", in the sense that there is no guarantee the pointer is of the proper type, it only checks if the first 4 bytes it points to contains STRUCT_1 or STRUCT_2.

Now, if you don't control the definition of those records, you're out of luck.

Comment: *" if you don't control the definition of those records, you're out of luck"* - Once you go out of context, he is not. E.g., change the definition of the function to accept a struct type parameter...

Comment: I mean, the answer to the question is clearly no. It seems like this just answers a different question. And as @sertac says, if you are prepared to change the rules then of course you can get a different answer.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz ...or as that point, declare 2 functions as `DoSomething1(P: Pointer)` and `DoSomething2(P: Pointer)`.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan The answer is clearly YES, it's possible. Granted, to be able to do so, there are prerequisites. And sadly, you can't, from the pointer alone, validate those prerequisite are met. What I describe here is pretty much how the IS operator work for TObject. So while determining the type of a randomly selected pointer is, indeed, impossible (or at the very least, insanely unreliable), answering a mere "No" to this questions feels quite incomplete to me.

Comment: The answer is clearly no you can't, for the question asked by the asker.

Comment: You both have valid points so I cannot accept only one of the answers

Comment: @GeorgiBonchev You can accept an answer. You decide which one you feel best answers the question you asked, and accept that. Nobody has any issue with you picking one.

Answer (score 4):

> Is there a way to determine if the function is called with P1 or P2 variable?

No there is not.

Answer (score 0):

A pointer is a kind of variable that can store a memory address or a special [`nil`](http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/RTL.asp?Name=Nil) value.

It can point to anything, to a valid or invalid, already destroyed object, to a variable, to a third char in a string or to another pointer.

But it store just the memory address, nothing more. There is no way to know the type from a memory address. If you need the type or other info, you should take care yourself about it.

For homogeneous structures an approach is to store its type or version in the first byte of the structure and later pointing a matched PStructureX on the pointer address, like in Ken's answer.